# DNS Setup for mail to two different servers

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, email, mx-record

I have a `stage.domainX.com` and `domainX.com`. How do I adjust the MX records accordingly to where all mail sent to `stage.domainX.com` goes to one server (IP1 66.xx.xx.xx) and all other mail sent to `domainX.com` goes to another server (IP2 67.xx.xx.xx)?

```
info@stage.domainX.com -> IP1
info@domainX.com -> IP2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have DNS records for the mail servers, for example:

```
mail1.domainX.com.         IN    A     66.xx.xx.xx
mail2.domainX.com.         IN    A     67.xx.xx.xx
```

Then create an `MX` record for each domain:

```
stage.domainX.com.         IN    MX    10 mail1.domainX.com.
domainX.com.               IN    MX    10 mail2.domainX.com.
```

Answer (score -2):

The correct way of doing it would be the delegating stage.domainX.com
Refer to the documentation to delegate stage.domainX.com
http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch9/delegate.html

Comment: Delegating is completely unnecessary in this situation.  In fact, it would only complicate things by requiring at least one more nameserver to delegate to.